# Construct space and measure on it in order to make unitary equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A : l_2 \to l_2 \quad A(x_1,\dots ,x_n ,\dots) = (\lambda_1 x_1,\dots,\lambda x_n,\dots)$ where all $\lambda_i$ different and $\{\lambda_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ - bounded sequence of real numbers. I need to pick up segment $[a,b]$ and measure on it in order to make operator $A$ unitary equivalent to multiplication operator by function $t$ in space $L_2([a,b] , \mu)$.

Comment: Whats the spectrum of $A$?

Comment: The spectrum is closure of $\{\lambda_j\}$

Comment: Can you think of a measure on that set so that multiplication with the variable has the same spectrum? As an easier example start with a finite dimensional Hilbert space, what kind of measure naturally lives on the spectrum in this case?

Comment: The classification should be same, so that I need the measure of one point be positive?

Comment: Yes, you can work with a sum of dirac measures.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dirac measures. Is it we juct claim $\mu(A)=1$ if some $x_0 \in A$ and $0$ in other case? If that we can just take the sum of that Dirac measures in points $\lambda_j$ to be our new measure?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: unitarily equivalent operators have the same spectrum. The spectrum of a multiplication operator is the essential range of it's corresponding function. So, it is only reasonable to think as follows:

Since the operator $A:\ell^2\to\ell^2$, $(x_n)\mapsto(\lambda_nx_n)$ has spectrum $\overline{\{\lambda_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$, consider any interval $[a,b]$ such that $\{\lambda_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset(a,b)$. Then, define the measure $\delta$ on $\mathcal{P}([a,b])$ by $\delta(E)=\text{number of $\lambda_i$ contained in $E$}.$ Then, you can prove that $A$ is unitarily equivalent with $M_t$ where $t$ is the identity function on $[a,b]$ and $M_t:L^2([a,b],\delta)\to L^2([a,b],\delta)$ is the multiplication operator by $t$.

**Edit**: I am adding the construction of the unitary operator. It is important to keep in mind that in $L^p$ spaces two functions $f,g$ are equal if and only if they are equal almost everywhere. Therefore, in $L^2([a,b],\delta)$, two functions are equal if and only if $f(\lambda_i)=g(\lambda_i)$ for all $i$.

We now define $U:\ell^2\to L^2([a,b],\delta)$ given by $U(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty=f$, where $f(\lambda_i)=x_i$ for all $i$ and $f=0$ everywhere else.
The operator is surjective: Indeed, let $f$ be a function of $L^2([a,b],\delta)$. Then we have $\int_{[a,b]}|f(x)|^2d\delta(x)<\infty$, but by the way we defined the measure $\delta$, we see that this integral is simply $\sum_{i=1}^\infty|f(\lambda_i)|^2$. Since this series converges, the sequence $(f(\lambda_i))_{i=1}^\infty$ is an element of $\ell^2$ and it is mapped to $f$ through $U$.
The operator preserves inner product: Simply notice that for $f,g\in L^2([a,b],\delta)$ it is $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\overline{g(x)}d\delta(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(\lambda_i)\overline{g(\lambda_i)}$. Now it is immediate that $U$ preserves inner product.

Since surjective+preserving inner product = unitary, we are done.

I leave it for you to verify that $UAU^{-1}=M_t$.

Comment: $P([a,b])$ it's just how you note $\sigma$-algebra on segment?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO Yes, I mean the set of all subsets of $[a,b]$.

Comment: From now I need to construct unitary operator?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO Yes. I think it is not hard to think of the operator. Remember: $[a,b]\setminus\{\lambda_n:n\geq1\}$ is of $\delta$ measure 0!

Comment: The first idea is to use fourier series and its coefficients. I will try to workout this problem.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO As you wish:)

Comment: Actually I still can't construct it...

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO You mean you cannot construct the unitary operator? If you want I can edit my post to add the details.

Comment: Yes, I mean I can’t construct operator. Could you, if you don’t mind?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO If the answer seems to cover your question now, please accept it so its not marked unanswered!